# Handle multiple pointer events in IE11 Metro/Mobile with pan-x and pan-y touch-action allowed

Tags: touch, internet-explorer-11, surface, pointer-events

I have a web application where I want to handle the pinch zooming gesture in javascript rather than allowing the browser to scale all of the UI. In IE11, it's my understanding that you need to specify a touch-action CSS on the element you wish to handle pointer events for.

In my application, I've disabled all touch behavior except for panning (touch-action: pan-x pan-y). I've wired up the pointerdown, pointerup, and pointermove events in javascript and I've added my own calculations to determine the level of zoom to perform based on distance between two active pointers (pinch gesture).

In IE11 on the desktop, this works exactly as I'd expect; however, on the mobile/metro version of IE (I've been testing on surface pro), I can never seem to detect more than one pointer event at a given time. It simply fires a pointercancel on the first captured event and fails to fire the second pointerdown. If I disable all touch gestures (touch-action: none), I'm able to get the multi-touch pointer events in the mobile browser as well, but it no longer allows panning, which is undesirable.

Here's a simple jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqgg0Ly7/22/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var pointers = [];

    function pointerDown(e)
    {
        pointers.push(e);

        if (pointers.length >= 2)
            alert("multiple pointers detected");
    };

    function pointerOut(e)
    {
         for (var i in pointers)
             if (pointers[i].pointerId == e.pointerId)
                 pointers.splice(i, 1);
    };

    $(".container")
        .on("pointerdown", pointerDown)
        .on("pointerout", pointerOut)    
        .on("pointercancel", pointerOut);
    });
};
```

If you test this in the Desktop version of IE11 on a touch-enabled device, you can pinch either one of these DIVs and you'll see the alert that two pointers were detected. Doing this same test in IE11 mobile, and only the first DIV will detect the second pointer; however, it doesn't allow panning like the second DIV.

Is this simply a bug in IE Metro or is there a work-around to allow panning on an element but still capture multiple pointer events?